# Showpost and last

Tags: plugins, php, categories

I need your help.

I would like to bring up the last (number) from my template classified ads. 
Here's the code:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'showposts' => 10,
            'post_type' => 'ad',
            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'ad_category',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => array('8')
                                )
                            )
    ));
if($the_query->have_posts()):
?>
<div class="feat-ad column col12"><!-- featured ad -->
     <h3 class="widget-title">Category</h3>
    <ul id="first-carousel" class="first-and-second-carousel">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <?php colabs_image('width=150&height=150&play=true');?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>   
    </ul>
</div><!-- end featured ad -->
<?php endif;?>
```

I tried with showpost, but nothing appears in one ad ... this is not even the last announcement.

Comment: `showposts` is long since deprecated. Use `posts_per_page`, but beyond that it is not clear what you are asking. "...nothing appears in one ad..."?

Comment: "I would like to bring up the last (number) from my template classified ads" Please clear this up. It is very confusing. If you need someone to help you you need to be a bit more clearer. If English is not your native tongue, get someone to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'ad',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'ad_category',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => array('8')
                                )
                            )
    ));
```

- `posts_per_page` tells how many items you want to retrieve from DB
- `orderby` tells to order items by date (optional as this is the default value)
- `order` is set to `DESC` to retrieve from newest to oldest items

Comment: Nothing, unfortunately. : (

Comment: @Marco there was two request already to give more info so that we can help you properly. And what does not happen with the code given in this answer